# посчитать вхождения в массив

Tags: javascript

Считаю вхождения `true` в массив. Помогите разобраться как сделать проверку на 0, undefined, null

```js
var array1 = [true, true, true, false,
  true, true, true, true,
  true, false, true, false,
  true, false, false, true,
  true, true, true, true,
  false, false, true, true
];


function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  var count = 1;
  arrayOfSheep.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {

    if (currentValue === true)
      count++;
  });
  return count;
}

console.info(countSheeps(array1));
```

1. Не пойму почему если поставить `count = 0`, количество true считается не верно.
2. Если передать пустой массив, не пойму как вывести 0.

Хочу понять как можно просто посчитать число вхождений `true` в массив, при этом учесть проверку на `null` и `undefined`

Comment: о каких null и undefined речь, если в примере только true и false?

Comment: @Grundy хочу обработать ситуацию, когда в array1 будет пустой массив, или он будет равняться null / undefined.

Comment: эм, массив будет равняться null/Undefined?

Comment: Я обновил ответ.

Comment: тут я массив рассматриваю как входные данные. незнаю что может там придти

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо делать так:

```js
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  return arrayOfSheep ? arrayOfSheep.reduce(function(count, value) {
    return count + (value === true);
  }, 0) : 0;
}

console.log(countSheeps([true, true, true, false,
  true, true, true, true,
  true, false, true, false,
  true, false, false, true,
  true, true, true, true,
  false, false, true, true
]));

console.log(countSheeps([]));
console.log(countSheeps(null));
console.log(countSheeps());
console.log(countSheeps([1,2,3,true,false,"true",17,null]));
```

> Не пойму почему если поставить count = 0, количество true считается не верно.

Потому что в твоей реализации первое значение в массиве вообще не обрабатывается.

Comment: вместо `value === true` можно просто `+value` :)

Comment: @Grundy, если там только булеаны, то можно и без плюса. А если нет, то это не одно и то же.

Comment: +(value||0) например :)

Comment: @Grundy, просили посчитать true. И не просили считать единицы. Если нужно просто все истинные значения, то `!!value`.

Answer (score 3):

Вы неправильно используете `.reduce`

```js
var array1 = [true, true, true, false,
  true, true, true, true,
  true, false, true, false,
  true, false, false, true,
  true, true, true, true,
  false, false, true, true
];


function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  return (arrayOfSheep||[]).reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {

    if (currentValue === true)
      previousValue++;
    return previousValue;
  }, 0);
};

const countSheeps2 = list => (list||[]).reduce((c, s)=>s===true?c+1:c, 0)

console.info(countSheeps(array1));
console.info(countSheeps2(array1));
```

Answer (score -2):

Функция "магическим" способом, подсчитывает количество `true` в массиве

```js
var array1 = [true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true];


function countSheeps(arrayOfSheeps) {
  return arrayOfSheeps.filter(Boolean).length;
}


console.info(countSheeps(array1));
```

Comment: в ответ стоит писать не просто непонятный кусок кода, но и какое-нибудь пояснение к нему. К тому же твое решение не отвечает на твой же собственный вопрос

Comment: input: `[1, 'a', true]`, expected: `1`, actual: `3`

Comment: за что минусим , товарищи !